# Wordpress Get Post by its category tried wordpress article

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying get the post by its category in WordPress i have category section in my panel and i have added the category as English but when i try to supply that in the array is see no change when added `category` attribute when `category_name` is added it return nothing

```
$book = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'paged'=> $paged,
     'category'         => 'English',
    'category_name'    => 'English',
     'posts_per_page'         => '12'
);
```

Comment: Do you use `query_posts` or `WP_Query` to get data from database ?

Comment: @MouradKaroudi thanks for the reply but am not sure let me check if i can find it out

Comment: category probably shouldn't be capitalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category parameters work only for default WordPress posts.
With custom post types you must use tax_query.

```
new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'your_custom_taxonomy_slug_here',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'english',
        )
    ),
) );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: `$book = array(
 'post_type' => 'book',
 'paged'=> $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'urdu',
        )
    )`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
$book = array(
  'post_type'      => 'book',
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'category_name'  => 'english',
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $book );
```

There is no parameter called 'category'. All category parameters:

- cat (int) - use category id.
- category_name (string) - use category
  slug.
- category__and (array) - use category id.
- category__in (array) -
  use category id.
- category__not_in (array) - use category id.

So, if you use 'category name' query get the posts that have these categories, using category slug.

For more details see [this link to Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Comment: `$book = array(
 'post_type' => 'book',
 'paged'=> $paged,
      'category_name'  => 'Urdu',
  'posts_per_page'         => '12'
);`  tried not working\

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
$custom_terms = get_terms('english');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'book',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'english',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
  print_r($loop);die;
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile; 
     }
}
```

Note that The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces).